# SSLCipherSuite with RC4-AES only

Tags: ssl

I submitted my LAMP server (redhat os) for two PCI compliance scans.  The first scan resulted in 3 SSL errors.  They were:

1. SSL Server Supports Weak Encryption for SSLv3, TLSv1
2. SSL Server Supports Weak MAC Algorithm for SSLv3, TLSv1
3. SSL Server Supports CBC Ciphers for SSLv3, TLSv1

The PCI scan report suggested some solutions, which I took in creating a SSLCipherSuite to address the issue.  This is the resulting SSLCipherSuite

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!MD5:!IDEA-CBC-SHA:!IDEA-CBC-MD5:!RC2-CBC-MD5:!DES-CBC-SHA:!DES-CBC-MD5:!EXP-DES-CBC-SHA:!EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:!EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:!ADH-DES-CBC-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:!EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:!EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:!EXP-ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
```

However, this SSLCipherSuite still failed issue 3.  The operator of the PCI Scan emailed me afterwards saying that i have to remove anything CBC based (such as DES).  The operator said he's frequently seen leaving RC4-AES as the available cipher as an acceptable solution.

So I took his suggestion and tried

```
SSLCipherSuite !ALL:RC4-AES
```

But this caused an error with apache and it wouldn't start up again.  What is the correct directive to do as the operator suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think he meant `RC4-SHA`, as `RC4-AES` is invalid (and contradictory).  Try that.

Oh, and don't do `SSLCipherSuite !ALL:RC4-SHA`, as that bans the `RC4-SHA` that you're trying to enable.  Just do `SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA`.

Comment: thanks Shane, the server accepted buth SSLCipherSuite RC4-AES and SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA .  I'm going to go with RC4-SHA as you suggest.